# Как в Android Studio отключить всплывающие подсказки?

Tags: android-studio, всплывающее-окно

Подскажите, как в Android Studio отключить всплывающие подсказки?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Судя по всему это не отключается.

Answer (score 1):

Открыть меню **File** | **Setting**s | **IDE Setting** | **Editor** и убрать флажок у пункта **Show quick doc on mouse move**.

Comment: Он и не стоит...

Comment: так другие подсказки выключаются